# concat values for search in jquery

Tags: jquery-mobile

suffering with a momentary lapse....

using jquery, i need to so a search (find) on a page that was filled in from an ajax call.  These new items fill a collapsable jquerymobile control.    Each of the items that are entered are id'd with a name and the ID that was returned from the database....

so if there were 50 items returned from the database, the id's of them would be slm1, slm2... slm50

now i need to perform an update to the item - later on in the page life cycle.

so now, i need to update the values of these items, so using jquery, is there a way i can do a find across the page using a concatenated value??

```
$('body').find("#slm35").each(function () {
              alert("test");
            });
```

the outer loop (of updated values) will roll through the 1 to 50 items, so in the code above, the #slm35 will need to be #slm1, #slm2, #slm3... #slm50

I was thinking this....

```
$('body').find("#slm" + id).each(function () {
              alert("test");
            });
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could select elements that have an id that begins with'slm', like so:

```
$('[id^="slm"]).each(function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

This should give you a jQuery collection containing all the items.  You could figure out the numeric id from the element if you like too:

```
$('[id^="slm"]).each(function(){
    var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(3), 10);
});
```

I'm not sure if this would be faster or slower than looping over ids elements and selecting the elements individually.  Sounds like a job for http://jsperf.com/